# FileInfo.Length is not giving me the correct file size always

Tags: c#, client-server

I am facing a very strange issue with `FileInfo` and the `Length` property. I am writing a server that responds to calls to send files (mainly images) to the clients. I want to send the file size to the client before I send the actual file. I am using `FileInfo` to find the file size but strangely it does not give me the correct size every time. Put differently, for the same file I receive different sizes, sometimes less than the actual size and sometimes correct (but never more than the actual size). What makes the problem even more strange, if I copy the same code to a new project (not a server, just a test project) it works fine and gives correct answers. The server use threads so multiple clients can connect (the test project doesn't) but I don't think that this has anything to do with `FileInfo`. Here is my code:

```
String fullFilePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\" + imageName;
FileInfo file1 = new FileInfo(fullFilePath);
Console.Writeline("File Size: {0}", file1.Length);
```

Very basic code! My images are small in the range of 4 to 10 Kbytes only. Am I doing something wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you measuring the actual size?

Comment: Sounds like you need to limit your server to only requesting the file info for a specific file one at a time.

Comment: @SLaks I am measuring the actual size from 3 ways: (1) when I load the file into `byte` array it gives me the correct size, (2) on the client I measure the size on disk, (3) on the server since I have access to it, I simply right click on the file and read the properties.

Comment: @Tejs per one client the server only responds to one request. Anyway in my test there is only one request since I am the only client.

Comment: I think I got it! The source images are not originally on the server, they come from clients. It seems that a request to download an image is coming before the server finishes saving the received image so it is giving different sizes every time (depending on hoe much bytes were saved at the moment of the request). I delayed the request by 1 sec and the problem didn't appear again. I think this is the problem and this solves it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it after all! The problem was not in the `FileInfo` class, the problem was a concept problem in my client server communication. The images originally are not on the server, they come from another clients. What was happening is that a client was sending an image to the server, and a request to get this image was reaching the server from another client but **before** the server actually finished saving the image on the disk. Therefore the `FileInfo` was getting the `Length` of the currently saved bytes and not the total bytes of the file.

The solution was as follows: when a file was sent to the server, allow some time (for example 1 second) for the server to finish the saving process before this file can become ready to be downloaded by other clients.